# Was the Russian Federation ever an actual democracy?

Tags: democracy, russian-federation, authoritarianism

Currently, it is a pretty established fact that Russia isn't a democracy. According to the vast majority of American news sources covering last year's Russian elections there, they are fake. However, the Russian Constitution ostensibly is one of a democracy, from what I know of it. I know that Putin has made major changes to the Constitution.

**Did the modern Russian Federation ever work as a democracy?** Or, since it replaced the Soviet Union, has it always had fake elections, major *de facto* and/or *de jure* restrictions on freedom of speech, etc.?

Comment: With removing opinion-based fragments about elections and so on, it'll be a good question, don't you think?) It is even more interesting, if you ask was it ever in its history or not.

Comment: I'm inclined to vote to close as not asked in good faith - it assumes that Russia isn't a democracy. What is fair (this word is *so* loaded) to one person might not be fair to another. Plus, as Orangesandlemons points out above, Putin is genuinely popular enough that it's very conceivable he'd win a "fair" general election anyway.

Comment: Comments deleted. Comments should be used to improve the question, not to discuss its subject matter and certainly not for discussing subject matters which have nothing to do with the question. For more information on how comments should and should not be used, please review the article about [the commenting privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) on the help center.

Answer (score 17):

If we use the [Democracy Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy_Index) to quantify the level of democracy in a country, the answer would be **no** in the time from 2006 till today.
The main problems nowadays in Russia are:

- limited freedom of press
- suppression of the opposition
- no protection or even persecution of minorities
- missing equality of people, for example prosecution of homosexuals
- probably rigged elections

Sadly, I have no data prior to 2006 right now, but I assume that Russia never was a "full democracy". But by this definition, neither is the US.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answers above, the Democracy Index ranks Russia as an authoritarian regime.
[image: Rank for how democratic a nation is.]

Basically, [Russia ranks as a 3.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy_Index) as of 2019, making it an authoritarian regime by the indexes' standards and below a flawed democracy like the United States or even a hybrid regime like Liberia. The index is based around ["60 indicators grouped in five different categories, measuring pluralism, civil liberties and political culture"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democracy_Index). While it is not a perfect indicator, it is the closest thing I believe we have to attempts to objectively measure how 'democratic' a nation is.

Comment: Those index ranks are very useful! For example, pandemia readiness index from 2019:
https://www.ghsindex.org/#l-section--map - it describes reality in a very 'accurate' manner.

Comment: @user2501323 Well not all indexes are perfect, but they are some of the closest things we have to objective evidence, otherwise people can make a lot of subjective arguments about these subjects. Plus, these indexes are made by very different people and I think the GHS index is talking about pandemic readiness in terms of resources and capacity to bring in experts to handle pandemics - whether people use those resources  or actually listen to their experts on how to use them when responding to a pandemic is another story...

Comment: In fact, you are right - as all statistics, it is done by humans and for humans, and may or may not describe reality or their views. It would be interesting to view, for example, Chinese version of such rating.

Answer (score -1):

The 1996 election, the first since the breakup of the Soviet Union, was the only Presidential election that went to a runoff.  Boris Yeltsin finished with the most votes, but far short of a majority.  He faced Gennady Zyuganov in the second round, and won by a 54-41 margin (with 5% voting "against all").

All subsequent elections were won by the incumbents (or their hand-picked successors) in the first round:

- 2000: 53% Putin
- 2004: 71% Putin
- 2008: 71% Medvedev
- 2012: 64% Putin
- 2018: 77% Putin

Comment: In this election, was there any credible evidence against its realness?

Comment: Just looking at election results isn't necessarily a proof of undemocratic elections. You have to look at how those results came to be. Was the media independent from the government? Was the opposition allowed to organize and campaign without government interference? Was the voting done in a fair way? Were there no notable irregularities during the count?

Comment: I'm sorry, but 1996 elections were nearly fully falcificated by the US. Without US support, Zyuganov would just won in the first tour. There even was a TIME journal about it

Comment: @user2501323 If you can find that article, it would make for a very interesting answer.

Comment: @user2501323 http://content.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,984833,00.html https://ccisf.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/201612201405.pdf

Comment: @KeithMcClary, exactly.) I've done answer around that, but it was removed as opinion-based and non-answering.

Comment: I'm more curious about why medvedev was elected in 2008?  if it wasn't a free eleciton how did someone temporarily supplant Putin?

Comment: @dsollen The Russian constitution forbids a president running for more than two consecutive terms, consequently Putin asked his Prime Minister to run for the presidency, and his supporters knew this.  During this time there was no ambiguity about who was really in charge.

Comment: @user2501323 The TIME article does not allege any manipulation or falsification or even any initiative or intervention from the US government, it just claims that Yeltsin hired some Americans to do what counts there as proper campaigning.

Comment: @inappropriateCode Err... who was? Did it ever occur to you that Putin is not a singular overmind, but there's a team of people with similar mindset. And that their policies are generally supported here in Russia. So yes, Medvedev can be in charge while still maintaining course very similar to Putin's. If you want to imply that Putin somehow manipulated him you'd have to provide some Medvedev decision that was overridden by Putin "from the shadows".

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov I'm not suggesting any of this is covert or conspiratorial, it's plainly obvious.  As you say Putin already is popular, but also appoints only loyalists to high office, further consolidating his influence.  For example, he created the National Guard, answerable to the executive (not interior ministry or defence ministry), and their leader is (of course) Putin's former bodyguard.  It's like Stalin, he was popular but also appointed only loyalists and was basically the only one making executive decisions.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov It might actually be a direct relationship, that if a leader is popular the people want him to appoint people who are more loyal and less independently minded, because they want to see his power amplified in government.

Comment: @inappropriateCode Yes, exactly. And following what people want sounds pretty democratic to me.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov But how, without a free and independent source of news/reporting, do we, or you, _really_ know that is what _the people_ want?

Comment: About 40 or even 30 years ago prosecution of homosexuals was normal in quite every western state, so what does this to do with democracy?